# Google play store in-app billing

Tags: android, google-play

I've recently developed an app that I am soon to put on the Google play store. In this app I plan on adding one in-app purchase that once purchased allows the user to change colour settings(background & text).

I realised that checking the Google play store is unnecessary every time the application runs, especially if the purchase has been made already.It may also cause a problem if the user doesn't have GPRS/Wifi when using the app!

I was therefore thinking about creating a shared preference which would act as the condition to check whether the user has purchased the in-app purchase.

Is there any other way that is maybe more secure? as I've read shared preferences can be altered quite easily.

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a Look http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/03/how-to-inegrate-in-app-purchase-billing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).

Or you can save purchased status in secure way using some **Encrypted** text either in shared preference or in database. So it gets harder to manipulate it.

**Encryption example:**

Encrypt:

```
 MCrypt mcrypt = new MCrypt();
 String encrypted = MCrypt.bytesToHex(mcrypt.encrypt("Text to Encrypt"));
```

Decrypt:

```
MCrypt mcrypt = new MCrypt();
String decrypted = new String(mcrypt.decrypt(encrypted));
```

Mcrypt.java

```
public class MCrypt {

    private String iv = "fedcba9876543210";//Dummy iv (CHANGE IT!)
    private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
    private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
    private Cipher cipher;
    private String SecretKey = "0123456789abcdef";//Dummy secretKey (CHANGE IT!)

    public MCrypt() {
        ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

        keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");

        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(String text) throws Exception {
        if (text == null || text.length() == 0) throw new Exception("Empty string");

        byte[] encrypted = null;

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(padString(text).getBytes());
        try { 
            encrypted = android.util.Base64.encode(encrypted, android.util.Base64.NO_PADDING);
        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
        }

        return encrypted;
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(String code) throws Exception {
        if (code == null || code.length() == 0) throw new Exception("Empty string");

        byte[] decrypted = null;

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

        try { 
            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(android.util.Base64.decode(code, android.util.Base64.NO_PADDING));
        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
        }
        return decrypted;
    }



    private static String padString(String source) {
        char paddingChar = ' ';
        int size = 16;
        int x = source.length() % size;
        int padLength = size - x;

        for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++) {
            source += paddingChar;
        }

        return source;
    }
}
```

**Reference:**

[128 bit encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15357387/1288725)